# Transform Sub to UDF getting (#VALUE!)

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, custom-function

I have a program `Sub` which works well. I want to convert  it into a custom Function, but when I use this function in Excel an error (`#VALUE!`) occurs

```
Function ТридцатьТРи(Diapozon As Integer)
    'для п/пр

    Dim k, n As Integer
    Dim parRange As Range

    Set parRange = Range("Diapozon")
    k = 0
    n = 0
    For Each Cell In parRange.Rows
        If Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1 And k = -1 Then
            n = n - 1
        End If
        If Cell.Value = 1 And k = -1 Then
            n = n + 1
        End If

        If Cell.Value = 1 Then
            k = k + 1
            If k = 2 Then
                k = -1

            End If
        End If
        If Cell.Value = 2 Or Cell.Value = 3 Then
            k = 0
        End If
    Next Cell

    ТридцатьТРи = n

End Function
```

[image: Function]

Comment: You are passing a range to a function expecting an Integer. You are never using the input of the function. And is there a named range "Diapozon"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the **UDF** code below (not sure about what you are trying to achieve with your logics inside the UDF), but it works (not getting `#VALUE!`).

Since you want to pass a `Range` object to the UDF (according to your screen-shot), you need to define it also in your `Function` code.

***Code***

```
Function cyrilic(Diapozon As Range) As Long

    Dim k As Long, n As Long
    Dim C As Range

    k = 0
    n = 0

    For Each C In Diapozon.Rows
        If C.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1 And k = -1 Then
            n = n - 1
        End If

        If C.Value = 1 And k = -1 Then
            n = n + 1
        End If

        If C.Value = 1 Then
            k = k + 1
            If k = 2 Then
                k = -1
            End If
        End If
        If C.Value = 2 Or C.Value = 3 Then
            k = 0
        End If
    Next C

    cyrilic = n

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work as a worksheet function apperently, you need to input the range that you previousely defined with a named range "diapozon" as an input range.

```
Function cyrillic(rng As Range)

    Dim k, n As Integer
    Dim parRange As Range

    Set parRange = rng
    k = 0
    n = 0
    For Each Cell In parRange.Rows

    If Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1 And k = -1 Then
    n = n - 1
    End If

    If Cell.Value = 1 And k = -1 Then
    n = n + 1
    End If

    If Cell.Value = 1 Then
    k = k + 1
    If k = 2 Then
    k = -1

    End If
    End If
    If Cell.Value = 2 Or Cell.Value = 3 Then
    k = 0
    End If


    Next Cell

    cyrillic = n

End Function
```

Just type : `=cyrillic("R1:RX")` and it should work.

Comment: I change code as you said , but result is the same (#Value!)

Comment: Ok, then maybe the issue is not the function but rather the input. How does your file look like and could there be something wrong or have you changed some of the "Diapozon" named range in a way that would influence the code?

Comment: i edit my question , with PrintScreen , could you look at it ?